# .net WPF, заставить ComboBox показывать сразу все элементы сразу

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Мне нужно, чтобы при раскрытии `ComboBox` показывались сразу все элементы, без скроллинга, но почему то на некоторых компьютерах лист в половину размера. (что примечательно, такое случается на ноутбуках)

Вот стиль

```
<Style x:Key="comboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF00BB2B"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton 
                        Name="ToggleButton" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                        Style="{x:Null}" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        Focusable="True" 
                        Background="#FF00BB2B"
                        Foreground="Green"
                        Visibility="Hidden"
                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">

                            <Grid Name="DropDown"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border 
                            x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                            Background="#FF1B1B1B"

                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="#888888"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable"  Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Прошу помочь мне в решении данной проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам должно помочь увеличение `MaxDropDownHeight`. Учтите, что вы не сможете показать *как угодно много* элементов, т. к. высота окна ограничена.

Ну и выпадающий список комбобокса не раскроется на всю возможную высоту, если ваш комбобокс находится близко к краю экрана: максимум покажется только кусок до низа видимой области экрана.

Comment: 1) Если комбобокс открывается снизу экрана, то лист "выползает" наверх, в свободную область =)

2) У меня всегда одинаковое количество элементов, как мне можно подсчитать их суммарную высоту?

Comment: @ЯктенсТид: 1) Это да, но если комбобокс посередине экрана, а список длиннее половины экрана, то возникает проблема.

Comment: @ЯктенсТид: 2) А все элементы одинаковой высоты? Создайте один элемент с `Visibility = Hidden` (но не Collapsed!), подождите, пока пройдёт пробег лэйаута, и спросите `ActualHeight`. Потом умножайте на количество элементов.

Comment: Всё, спасибо, всё работает

Comment: @ЯктенсТид: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.